# Multiple versions of the local package within the pnpm registry

Tags: npm, monorepo, pnpm, pnpm-workspace

I'm currently trying to set up a monorepo with `pnpm`. I've got `apps` folder for the actual application and a `package` folder for shared packages between apps.

One of the use cases is to have package with TS type definitions for use for all apps, but there's a catch. Let's say, the backend server needs to implement a feature using amended typings and the frontend is to use the old ones before the refactoring can happen.

The current solution we came up with is to publish the package to the GH registry but this requires a lot of additional effort for new developers to be able to use it (setting auth etc.).

Is it possible to link different versions of the local package to each application? Using the `workspace:[version]` works only if the version specified is the same as in the `package.json` file of the package.

Comment: Why do you want to keep them in monorepo then?